# Finding max value using generic function

Tags: c

I am coding some stuff for myself an I want to write simple generic function, which finds max value in array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Pass array pointer, array length and size of element
void *getMaxAdr(void *array, int length, size_t size)
{
    char *maxAdr = (char*) malloc (size);

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (memcmp(maxAdr, array + i*size, size) < 0)
            maxAdr = (char *) array + i*size;
    }

    return maxAdr;
}

int main()
{
    int iarray[] = {3, 4, 1, 5, 2};
    char charray[] = {'A', 'C', 'E', 'B', 'D'};
    float farray[] = {2.2, 5.5, 3.3, 4.4, 1.1};
    double darray[] = {11.11, 22.22, 55.55, 33.33, 44.44};
    void *pMax;

    pMax = getMaxAdr(iarray, 5, 4);
    printf("\n%d\n", *(int *) pMax);

    pMax = getMaxAdr(charray, 5, 1);
    printf("\n%c\n", *(char *) pMax);

    pMax = getMaxAdr(farray, 5, 4);
    printf("\n%1.1f\n", *(float *) pMax);

    pMax = getMaxAdr(darray, 5, 8);
    printf("\n%2.2f\n", *(double *) pMax);

    return 0;
}
```

Function works fine for ints and chars, but when I pass array of floats, it return 4.4 for floats and 44.44 for doubles. What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: You are passing pointers to non-initialized heap memory to `memcmp()`, for starters ... Also not sure where you think you're computing the "max" of anything. Basically to do the comparison, you must use explicit types.

Comment: Please don't tag C questions as C++, a C++ solution would look *very* different.

Comment: Pick a language please.

Comment: I edit my code with comments to explain what I thing I am doing.

Comment: "I edit my code with comments to explain what I thing I am doing" Your **only** comment is completely useless, as it only states the obvious. This is a good example of how **not** to comment.

Comment: Maybe look in the documentation of qsort ( http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort ) as an example how such a goal you aim to could be achieved in plain C. In C language you can't figure out what type a pointer was pointing to, so you have to think about different solutions than something attempting to require that (qsort does it by accepting a comparator function, which must be written in a manner appropriate to the arrays you want to sort with it).

Comment: I've posted an answer with such a comparator function, similar to `qsort`, `bsearch` and other such generic functions.

Comment: Combine [@Lundin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32760080/2410359) answer with keyword `_Generic`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't make sense; how is `memcmp()` supposed to compute a maximum of anything larger than a byte? Note that [its return value](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcmp) only tells you the relationship between the two first differing *bytes*. That won't work for floating point data types, and it won't work for integers unless you assume big-endian. So, in short, it doesn't work.

You must use the proper types and an actual comparison operator to get the proper code for this. It won't be pretty, but C isn't very easy to make pretty generic code in.

Also your handling of `maxAdr` makes absolutely no sense, and leaks memory.

Comment: Specially the use of `malloc()` is completely unnecessary and it's leaking memory. I think the OP as many others I have seen in the past believes that `malloc()` is some kind of permission granting function that allows the programmer to use a pointer without making the program crash, and that is very very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that inside a generic function, you can't make any assumptions about how two chunks of binary data are related to each other. The caller must tell your function how to do so.

This is how to re-write your program into traditional generic C programming:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// declare a desired format for the generic comparison function:
typedef bool comp_func (const void* p1, const void* p2);

// write comparison functions ("functors") for all valid types:

bool more_int (const void* p1, const void* p2)
{
  return *(int*)p1 > *(int*)p2;
}

bool more_char (const void* p1, const void* p2)
{
  return *(char*)p1 > *(char*)p2;
}

bool more_float (const void* p1, const void* p2)
{
  return *(float*)p1 > *(float*)p2;
}

bool more_double (const void* p1, const void* p2)
{
  return *(double*)p1 > *(double*)p2;
}

// The actual function. 
const void* get_max_value (const void* arr,  // pointer to 1st element (base)
                           size_t arr_size,  // size of array 
                           size_t obj_size,  // size of one object
                           comp_func* more)  // comparison function
{
  const uint8_t* byte = arr;          // can't take the contents of void* so convert to bytes
  const void* max;                    // pointer to the largest value found

  if(more(&byte[0], &byte[obj_size])) // initialize max by comparing the first two objects
  {
    max = &byte[0];
  }
  else
  {
    max = &byte[obj_size];
  }

  for(size_t i=2; i<arr_size; i++) // start at index 2, index 0 and 1 already checked
  {
    if(more(&byte[i*obj_size], max))
    {
      max = &byte[i*obj_size];
    }
  }

  return max;
}


int main (void)
{
  int    iarray[]  = {3, 4, 1, 5, 2};
  char   charray[] = {'A', 'C', 'E', 'B', 'D'};
  float  farray[]  = {2.2f, 5.5f, 3.3f, 4.4f, 1.1f};
  double darray[]  = {11.11, 22.22, 55.55, 33.33, 44.44};
  const void *pMax;

  pMax = get_max_value(iarray,
                       sizeof(iarray)/sizeof(*iarray),
                       sizeof(*iarray),
                       more_int);
  printf("\n%d\n", *(const int*)pMax);

  pMax = get_max_value(charray,
                       sizeof(charray)/sizeof(*charray),
                       sizeof(*charray),
                       more_char);
  printf("\n%c\n", *(const char*)pMax);

  pMax = get_max_value(farray,
                       sizeof(farray)/sizeof(*farray),
                       sizeof(*farray),
                       more_float);
  printf("\n%1.1f\n", *(const float*) pMax);

  pMax = get_max_value(darray,
                       sizeof(darray)/sizeof(*darray),
                       sizeof(*darray),
                       more_double);
  printf("\n%2.2f\n", *(const double*) pMax);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5

E

5.5

55.55
```

Comment: Thank you all for answers! Again you helped me a lot :)